# IIS: Connecting to .mdf database - web config problem

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, mdf

Locally I connect to Northwind.mdf but when I upload application to remote server then I get following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

These are few options I tried:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

The above one work locally.

```
<connectionStrings>
            <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\ASP\TestSite\App_Data\Northwind.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes"/>
        </connectionStrings>
```

On server is installed SQL Server 2005

Thanks,
Ilija

Comment: Your connection string indicates **Express** edition, yet you mention only "SQL Server 2005" - what is it?? Is it SQL Server 2005 **Express** on your remote host, or a full version of SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:
1: Attach your Northwind.mdf to your Sql Server 2005 on your server using the Sql server Management studio.
2: Modify the connectionstring in your web.config so that it points to the db on your server.

[How to detach / attach db.](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/moving-the-database.html)

Comment: hi, i am also having the same problem.i have added the mdf file from visual studio in app_data folder. my connection string is _Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True_. i am uploading my projects through filezilla. so is there any other way to resolve the   problem

Comment: @ArjunVachhani you will have to attach your db on to your hosting db server.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to check:

1. Is the database file really at that location?
2. Does the app pool have read/write rights to that directory?
3. Are the SQL Express services actually running?

Answer (score 1):

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\ASP\TestSite\\App_Data\\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

And then read [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

And be sure the location of Northwind.mdf is right!

Answer (score 1):

Here's couple of points to check:

- If you're deploying into a shared hosting environment the chances are that the host won't be running SQL Server on the web servers. Ask them to confirm and provide you with the .
- The connection string you're using looks suspicious. If SQL server has been installed on your server but as the "Default" instance then you don't need the `\SQLEXPRESS` part of the connection string `Data Source`. Just use `.` or `(local)`.
- If it is indeed SQL Express installed and it's been installed with the instance name `SQLEXPRESS` then check that the site identity has a valid login and the correct permissions on your database. This identity could be the worker process account (`NETWORK SERVICE`, `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, custom account) or the site's IIS anonymous account (if ASP.NET impersonation is enabled).

My final point is important:

- The `AttachDbFilename` and `User Instance=True` are specific to SQL Express which supports a concept known as "[User Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx)". This feature is **not** suitable for dedicated or shared hosting environments.

My advice is to

- find out exactly what version AND *edition* of SQL Server is available for you to use
- find out where its hosted (locally on your server, or on another machine)
- find out if it's configured as the "Default" instance or a named instance